# How to use AndroidInjection in base class?

Tags: dagger-2

I have a BaseUiFragment in base module, need inject a UiComponent.

```
public abstract class BaseUiFragment extends Fragment {
    @Inject
    UiComponent mUiComponent;

    @Override
    public final void onAttach(Context context) {
        AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this); //this is subclass
        super.onAttach(context);
    }
}

@Subcomponent
public interface BaseUiFragmentSubcomponent extends AndroidInjector<BaseUiFragment> {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<BaseUiFragment> {
    }
}

@Module(subcomponents = BaseUiFragmentSubcomponent.class)
public abstract class BaseUiFragmentModule {
    @Binds
    @IntoMap
    @FragmentKey(BaseUiFragment.class) // key in MapProviderFactory
    abstract AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Fragment>
    bindBaseUiFragmentInjectorFactory(BaseUiFragmentSubcomponent.Builder builder);

    private BaseUiFragmentModule() {}
}
```

In app module, UiComponentModule provide UiComponent, MainFragment extends BaseUiFragment.

```
@Module
public class UiComponentModule {
    @Provides
    static UiComponent provideUiComponent() {
        return new UiComponent() {};
    }
}

@Singleton
@Component(modules = {AndroidSupportInjectionModule.class, BaseUiFragmentModule.class, UiComponentModule.class})
public interface ApplicationComponent extends AndroidInjector<MainApplication> {
    @Component.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<MainApplication> {
    }
}

public class MainFragment extends BaseUiFragment {
    @Override
    public View onCreateViewImpl(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return new View(getContext());
    }
}
```

when AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this); run， it does not work.
Because DispatchingAndroidInjector's maybeInject() return false

injectorFactories has (BaseUiFragment.class, ...) not has (MainFragment.class, ...), but AndroidSupportInjection.inject(this); this is MainFragment.

```
public boolean maybeInject(T instance) {
    Provider<AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends T>> factoryProvider =
        injectorFactories.get(instance.getClass());
    if (factoryProvider == null) { // factoryProvider is null
      return false;
    }
    // ...
}
```

So, How to use AndroidInjection(AndroidSupportInjection) in base class?

After a few days of analysis：

Google's inject impl:  it's **only instance.getClass()**

```
public boolean maybeInject(T instance) {
    Provider<AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends T>> factoryProvider =
            injectorFactories.get(instance.getClass());
    if (factoryProvider == null) {
        return false;
    }
    // ...
}
```

My impl: **traversal it and its superclass**，the problem is solved, but it use reflection that get the factoryProvider.

```
public boolean maybeInject(T instance) {
    Provider<AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Fragment>> factoryProvider
            = injectorFactories.get(fragment.getClass());
    Class fragmentSuperclass = fragment.getClass().getSuperclass();
    while (factoryProvider == null && fragmentSuperclass != Fragment.class) {
        factoryProvider = injectorFactories.get(fragmentSuperclass);
        fragmentSuperclass = fragmentSuperclass.getSuperclass();
    }
    if (factoryProvider == null) {
        return false;
    }
    // ...
}
```

So, is it only this way？ And Google can Change the implementation？

Answer (score 2):

You have only created a subcomponent that knows how to inject `BaseUiFragment`. Since that is all that dagger can see it will only know how to generate code to handle injecting the `BaseUiFragment`.

You need to create a subcomponent for each leaf of your inheritance hierarchy.

Something like this is how i like to do my fragment components

```
@Subcomponent
public interface MainFragmentComponent extends AndroidInjector<MainFragment> {
    @Subcomponent.Builder
    abstract class Builder extends AndroidInjector.Builder<MainFragment> {}

    @Module(subcomponents = MainFragmentComponent.class)
    abstract class BindingModule {
        @Binds
        @IntoMap
        @FragmentKey(MainFragment.class)
        abstract Factory<? extends Fragment> mainFragmentComponentBuilder(Builder impl);
    }
}
```

Comment: "create a subcomponent for each leaf of your inheritance hierarchy" is not a good way, I think.  it is not friendly for caller who use my base library.

Comment: @ApolunorJing Dagger is a _compile-time code-generating_ solution. If `FooFragment` has a field `@Inject Bar bar`, there's no way Dagger can populate it without inspecting it at compile time (so it can write a setter for it), and the way to tell it to do so is exactly as Trev has it here. +1 to the answer.